# Styled map freeze Android Mapbox 6.1.1

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-android

Im getting a screen freeze when using a styled map built using mapbox studio. The only thing we did in the styled map is add another layer.

We tested already running the map using the default style, and there is no problem, the custom-styled map gives lag(freeze screen) in the portion of the map where most of the data are there.

This lag only occur when using Mapbox 6.1.1, using Mapbox lower than version 6 wont give the error.